# How do i make sure that a datatype implement an IComparable interface

Tags: c#, interface

I need to make sure that a datatype implements the IComparable interface, and I was wondering if there was anyway to make that a requirement when you create the object?

Comment: Please clarify the question. I can think of a number of things you might mean, but they'd all have different answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can perhaps use generic to do this, for example:

```
public static T Create<T>() where T : IComparable<T>, new() {
    return new T();
}
```

Or if you mean "when you create the type" (in code), then no; you'd just have to remember, perhaps using unit-tests to verify that you've done it.

I recommend using the typed `IComparable<T>` over `IComparable` - it makes life a lot easier (and avoids some boxing, but that is less of an issue). Finally, remember that you can use `Comparer<T>.Default` and `Comparer.Default` in code if you want to duck-type the comparable bit (like how `List<T>.Sort()` works).

Answer (score 1):

For a generic class you can do:

```
public class MyType<T>
   where T:IComparable<T>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also might want to look into [Comparer<T>.Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azhsac5f.aspx).  From what I understand it gets the IComparable<T> first, if it can't find that then it gets the IComparable version, otherwise it throws an exception.

```
double s = 5;
double t = 10;
int result = Comparer<double>.Default.Compare(s, t);
```

Comment: I believe it will eventually throw if it can't find a suitable IComparable

Comment: Well, `IComparable<T>`, then `IComparable`, then throw (not `IComparer<T>` etc)